# Haskell filter more than one char

Tags: haskell

I have a question. I have this line of code here.

```
map length [filter (/= ' ') someString]
```

I know it removes the space from someString. But is it possible to remove more than just the space from the string using filter? Let just say remove the spaces and some other char.

Thanks!

Comment: `map length [filter (/= ' ') someString]` - does this compile?

Comment: @shree.pat18 It does, but it will always return ``[<length of non space chars>]`` if I am not mistaken. It is equivalent to ``return . filter (/= ' ') someString :: [Int]``

Comment: @ThreeFx My bad, missed the space and got parse error. But it won't always return [1].

Comment: yes it does and returns the length of the non space chars. But I wish to remove some other chars like the ! and so on.

Comment: @user4274735 Why are you using `map length`? `filter` will return the string just fine.

Comment: because I wish to know the length of the string. any string...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do:

```
filter (not . flip elem "<your chars here>")
```

Example:

```
ghci> filter (not . flip elem " .,") "This is an example sentence, which uses punctuation."
"Thisisanexamplesentencewhichusespunctuation"
```

Just to put the comment in here: To filter out letters of both cases (a-z and A-Z), you should probably use [`Data.Char`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Char.html)'s `isLetter` function.

Comment: Thanks that will do the trick! Is it possible to add a range of char like a-Z using flip?

Comment: @user4274735 Just use [``Data.Char``](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Char.html)'s ``isLetter`` for that.

Comment: I hope you do not mind me to ask this but how would it look like using isLetter?

Comment: @user4274735 ``isLetter x`` returns ``True`` if x is a letter, else it is ``False``. To invert it, just use ``not . isLetter``.

Comment: Well thanks I used like: map length [filter (isLetter) someString] and it did the trick thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

A slightly shorter way is to use `notElem`:

```
λ> filter (flip notElem " f") "foo bar"
"oobar"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a fold to get the length, if you don't actually need to return the filtered string but only want its length.

```
f x charlist = foldl (\acc x -> if not $ x `elem` charlist then acc + 1 else acc) 0 x
```

`charlist` is your list of banned characters. If you have a fixed list always, you can directly define it as a top-level value and use it in the function body instead of passing it as a parameter.

A more concise version using list comprehensions:

```
f x = length [z | z <- x, notElem z charlist]
```